# Show only the content that match topic

Tags: php, html

How can i show the only content that match the topic? 
This code will show **all** the 'topic' and the 'content' 
please help me

this is buzz(like a forum)

```
    <thead>
    <tr align="center">
        <th>Topic</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
    <tr align="center">
        <?php

            $sql = "SELECT buzz_topic FROM buzz";
            $result = $con->query($sql);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo"<tr>
                    <td><a href='buzzContent.php'>{$row['buzz_topic']}</a></td>
                    </tr>";
                }
            ?>
    </tr>

    <td><input type="button" value="Add Topic" onClick="document.location.href='addBuzz.php'"></td>

  </tbody>
  </table>

   </form>
```

this is to add the topic and detail into the buzz database

```
            <tr>
                <td>Student ID</td>
                <td> 
                    <textarea rows="1" cols="50" type='text' name='student_ID' id='student_ID'></textarea> 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Topic</td>
                <td>
                    <textarea rows="1" cols="50" type='text' name='buzz_topic' id='buzz_topic'></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Content</td>
                <td>
                      <textarea rows="5" cols="50" type='text' name='buzz_content' id='buzz_content'></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" ></td>
            <td><input type="button" onClick="history.go(0)" value="Cancel"></td>

        </form>
```

this is to show the content of buzz that people are click, but it will show all the content and topic, how can i solve it?

```
    <h1>
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT buzz_topic FROM buzz";
            $result = $con->query($sql);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['buzz_topic'];
            }
        ?>
    </h1>

    <p>
        <?php   

        $sql = "SELECT buzz_content FROM buzz";
        $result = $con->query($sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['buzz_content'];
        }
        ?>
    </p>

    <input type="button" onClick="document.location.href='buzz.php'" value="Back">

    </form>
```

Comment: most likely you'd use a `WHERE` clause

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. Please paste only the relevant code and show us the relevant table structure.

Answer (score 1):

use id as primary key. 
and pass the id when user clicks .

```
<?php
            $sql = "SELECT buzz_topic,buzz_content FROM buzz WHERE id=".$id."";
            $result = $con->query($sql);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<h>".$row['buzz_topic']."</h>";
            echo "<p>".$row['buzz_content']."</p>";
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your SQL statement needs a LIKE statement

```
SELECT buzz_content FROM buzz WHERE buzz_content LIKE '%searchterm%'
```